# Styling a facebook iframe on website

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-iframe

I've embedded a facebook page on my site :

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FIACTTV&width=1200&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=635" scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:1200px; height:930px; background: white;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

The box is showing up at 500px width and I can't seem to get the content to be 1200px. 
Anyone have experience styling a likebox iframe?

I've tried:

```
iframe #u_0_0 div {
    width: 1200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook only allows for a **max-width** of **500px** for plugins it seems.

From the Facebook developer docs:

> width - The pixel width of the plugin. Min. is 180 & Max. is 500

see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)